# ActionBarSherlock Background Style

Tags: android, styles, actionbarsherlock

To get the action bar blue I have been using the following code:

```
com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#00BFFF")));
```

But the code does not seem much handy when the user shifts to some other screen out of the apps control. I tried using the style attribute

```
<item name = "android:background">#00BFFF</item>
```

But this messes up the whole display of the application. Is there something that I am missing ?? Can someone please suggest me on this ? How do I implement a `actionbarsherlock` background ?

Answer (score 0):

Apply like this in your styles.xml

```
<!-- "Implementation" of our ABS custom theme -->
    <style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/TitleText</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_background</item>
        <item name="background">@drawable/ab_background</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/TitleText</item>
    </style>
```

in the `<item name="background">`create a drawable 9 patch for the actionbar background.